# Vim like navigation keys for Finder

Tags: keyboard, finder, vi

So I use [vim](https://www.vim.org) all the time, and I've grown use to the navigation keys <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>, (especially when navigating with NERDTree).

Does anyone know if it's possible to implement this motion in macOS Finder.app?

I thought of remapping the keys using something like [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) or [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/), but in either case, I would not be able to use those keys when renaming a file.

Comment: Linking to [Vim based textbox input](https://superuser.com/questions/1038365/systemwide-vim-mode-for-osx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim can get addictive once we get the hang of it. To **vim-ify** the Finder is a lovely idea.

However, what features are you thinking about? For example, browsing files using the navigation keys <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>, then pressing <kbd>i</kbd> to enter edit mode and rename files or folders?

Vim’s power lies in text mode, whereas macOS interface is designed to be used with a mouse/trackpad. It may be better to stick with vim to process textual information, and to use mouse/trackpad in a graphical environment.

By the way, I cannot see a simple and effective way to hack the Finder (as you said Karabiner is fantastic, but it just won't do it). It would probably require to program a specific macOS Finder utility using Swift.

**Alternatively**:

1. Some code editors can be controlled the **vim way**, like [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) with enabling the [Vintage Mode](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/vintage.html).
2. Web browsers can be controlled the **vim way**: Chrome with [Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb) or [cVim](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cvim/ihlenndgcmojhcghmfjfneahoeklbjjh), Firefox with [Vimium-FF](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/vimium-ff/) or [Vim Vixen](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/vim-vixen/) (thanks to @Ruslan and @wchargin for mentioning it)
3. The bash shell running in Terminal.app can be used in vi mode using `set -o vi` or `set editing-mode vi`.
4. There are great textual file managers ready to install via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) that worth a try, like:

   - [nnn](https://github.com/jarun/nnn). To install run `brew install nnn`.
   - [lf](https://godoc.org/github.com/gokcehan/lf). To install run `brew install lf`.
   - [vifm](https://vifm.info). To install run `brew lf`.
   - [ranger](https://ranger.github.io). To install run `brew install ranger`.
   - [midnight-commander](https://midnight-commander.org). To install run `brew install midnight-commander`. Run by typing `mc`.
   - [fdclone](https://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA012337/soft/fd/). To install run `brew install fdclone`. Run by typing `fd`.

Comment: `It may be better <...> to use mouse/trackpad in a graphical environment.` Not always. I consider modern web browsers graphical environments, and there used to be quite some extensions like Vimperator, which worked quite successfully (until broken by changing APIs). So there might have been a similarly useful extension for Finder.

Comment: @Ruslan: [Vimium-FF](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimium-ff/), based off its Chrome counterpart, works quite well with latest Firefox.

Comment: @Ruslan & wchargin Thanks for mentioning Vim navigation in browsers, I added it to the list.

Answer (score 3):

## Vim Motion

[Vim Motion](https://github.com/dwarvesf/VimMotionApp) is an open source app which fairly does what you ask, it does more than just with Finder including stuff like Launchpad and other UI elements.

> We are bringing vim-easymotion to macOS , where most UI elements can be accessed with your fingers stay on the keyboard. Hope vim users enjoy it as much as we do ♥️
>
> Along with the favorite Vimari ext on Safari or Vimium on Chrome, vim users will gain a new power.

Basic Movement:

### Hint mode

- <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> To show tags on UI.
- Type Tag title to filter and trigger action, Delete if you want to refilter tags. esc, <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> To dismiss tags.
- Spacebar to temporary hide tags for 0.75s. This helping you see contents under tags without dismiss and reopen Hint mode.
- Tab to show Switch window mode, Tab again to hide it.(This feature required Screen Recording permission to capture windows image for using as thumbnails)
- Easy to switch windows of Active workspace with Tab in Hint mode.

### Scroll Mode

- <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> To show scroll mode on UI.
- esc, <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> To dismiss scroll mode.
- Tab or Shift + Tab to navigate between Scroll area
- hjkl to scroll, you can go to Preferences window to revert J <-> K.

Surprising it has multi-monitor support, check the github for more documentation of usage

Answer (score 1):

Just found out about this **Vimac** app also recently, really impressive. It's like **Vimium** but for Mac UI/apps. You could customize the shortcuts and navigation keys:

App Website:
https://vimacapp.com

GitHub Page:
https://github.com/dexterleng/vimac

Personally, I prefer this over the **VimMotion** app since it's more stable, faster, and has more customization/settings.

Comment: Vimac has been deprecated by the developer as he created Homerow for the same use case. https://www.homerow.app/

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add [SurfingKeys](https://github.com/brookhong/Surfingkeys) to the list of VIM like plugins for Chrome.

Comment: The question relates to Finder, not Chrome.